# Visual Studio macro to collapse custom nodes

Tags: visual-studio

If I were to have something like:

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    #region Usings

    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Security;

    #endregion

    /// <summary> Implements a dictionary with several keys.                               </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="Value"> What type of elements we will be storing in the dictionary</typeparam>
    public class MultiKeyDic<Value>
    {

         /// <summary>  a very long summary that can be
         /// collapsed and expanded. </summary>
         public int SomeInt {get;set;}


         public void someMethod()
         {

         }
    }
}
```

How can I create a macro that will find all the places that can be expandable (Nodes). If I would like to collapse all the nodes I will have to collapse the nodes in the order of `someMethod()`, `summary of SomeInt` , `class MultiKeyDic`, `summary of class MultiKeyDic`, `#region Usings` and finally `namespace`.

I know the command <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> collapses everything, but I do not want to collapse everything. For example I might not want to collapse the comments. If I collapse everything and then expand the comments that expands the parent node too.

---

So far I have created this macro that will find most of the nodes:

```
Sub VisitAllNodes()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim fileCM As FileCodeModel
    Dim elts As EnvDTE.CodeElements
    Dim elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement

    fileCM = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel
    elts = fileCM.CodeElements
    For i = 1 To elts.Count
        elt = elts.Item(i)
        CollapseE(elt, elts, i)
    Next
End Sub

'' Helper to OutlineCode. Recursively outlines members of elt.
''
Sub CollapseE(ByVal elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement, ByVal elts As EnvDTE.CodeElements, ByVal loc As Integer)
    Dim epStart As EnvDTE.EditPoint
    Dim epEnd As EnvDTE.EditPoint

    epStart = elt.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes).CreateEditPoint()
    epEnd = elt.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes).CreateEditPoint() ' Copy it because we move it later.
    epStart.EndOfLine()
    If ((elt.IsCodeType()) And (elt.Kind <> EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementDelegate)) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim mems As EnvDTE.CodeElements

        mems = elt.Members
        For i = 1 To mems.Count

            Dim temp As EnvDTE.CodeElement = mems.Item(i)
            Dim t As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(EnvDTE.vsCMElement), temp.Kind)
            MsgBox("Found member (" & t & ") at line# " & temp.StartPoint.Line)

            CollapseE(mems.Item(i), mems, i)
        Next
    ElseIf (elt.Kind = EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) Then
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim mems As EnvDTE.CodeElements

        mems = elt.Members
        For i = 1 To mems.Count

            Dim temp As EnvDTE.CodeElement = mems.Item(i)
            Dim t As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(EnvDTE.vsCMElement), temp.Kind)
            MsgBox("Found member (" & t & ") at line# " & temp.StartPoint.Line)

            CollapseE(mems.Item(i), mems, i)
        Next
    End If

    'Return
    ' collapse the element

    If (epStart.LessThan(epEnd)) Then
        loc = loc + 1
        If (loc <= elts.Count) Then
            epEnd.MoveToPoint(elts.Item(loc).GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartHeader))
            epEnd.LineUp()
            epEnd.EndOfLine()
        End If
        epStart.OutlineSection(epEnd)
    End If
End Sub
```

It looks more complicated than what it is. Run it on any document and it will display all the properties, classes, enums, etc., but for some reason it does not find the comments nor regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first Function `IncludeMember` is used to determine what type of members to exclude. for example in this example I do not collapse namespaces and using directives:

```
' filter some mebers. for example using statemets cannot be collapsed so exclude them. 
    Function IncludeMember(ByVal member As EnvDTE.CodeElement)

        If member.Kind = vsCMElement.vsCMElementIDLImport Then
            Return False
        ElseIf member.Kind = vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace Then
            Return False  ' I do not want to colapse enums
        End If

        Return True

    End Function

    Sub CollapseNodes()

        ' activate working window
        DTE.Windows.Item(DTE.ActiveDocument.Name).Activate()

        ' expand everything to start

        Try
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.StopOutlining")
        Catch
        End Try

        Try
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.StartAutomaticOutlining")
        Catch
        End Try


        ' get text of document and replace all new lines with \r\n
        Dim objTextDoc As TextDocument
        Dim objEditPt As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim text As String
        ' Get a handle to the new document and create an EditPoint.
        objTextDoc = DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("TextDocument")
        objEditPt = objTextDoc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint
        ' Get all Text of active document
        text = objEditPt.GetText(objTextDoc.EndPoint)
        text = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace( _
                        text, _
                        "(\r\n?|\n\r?)", ChrW(13) & ChrW(10) _
                    )

        ' add new line to text so that lines of visual studio match with index of array
        Dim lines As String() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(vbCrLf & text, vbCrLf)

        ' list where whe will place all colapsable items
        Dim targetLines As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)

        ' regex that we will use to check if a line contains a #region
        Dim reg As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(" *#region( |$)")

        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To lines.Length - 1

            If reg.Match(lines(i)).Success Then
                targetLines.Add(i)
            End If

        Next


        Dim fileCM As FileCodeModel
        Dim elts As EnvDTE.CodeElements
        Dim elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement

        Dim projectItem = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem

        Dim temp = projectItem.Collection.Count

        Dim b = DirectCast(DirectCast(projectItem.Document, EnvDTE.Document).ActiveWindow, EnvDTE.Window).ContextAttributes

        fileCM = projectItem.FileCodeModel
        elts = fileCM.CodeElements
        For i = 1 To elts.Count
            elt = elts.Item(i)
            CollapseE(elt, elts, i, targetLines)
        Next

        ' now that we have the lines that we will plan to collapse sort them. it is important to go in order
        targetLines.Sort()

        ActivateWorkingWindow()

        ' go in reverse order so that we can collapse nested regions
        For i = targetLines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1


            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Goto", targetLines(i))

            DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ToggleOutliningExpansion")

        Next


    End Sub

    '' Helper to OutlineCode. Recursively outlines members of elt.
    ''
    Sub CollapseE(ByVal elt As EnvDTE.CodeElement, ByVal elts As EnvDTE.CodeElements, ByVal loc As Integer, ByRef targetLines As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer))
        Dim epStart As EnvDTE.EditPoint
        Dim epEnd As EnvDTE.EditPoint

        epStart = elt.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes).CreateEditPoint()
        epEnd = elt.GetEndPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartWholeWithAttributes).CreateEditPoint() ' Copy it because we move it later.
        epStart.EndOfLine()
        If ((elt.IsCodeType()) And (elt.Kind <> EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementDelegate) Or elt.Kind = EnvDTE.vsCMElement.vsCMElementNamespace) Then
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim mems As EnvDTE.CodeElements

            mems = elt.Members
            For i = 1 To mems.Count

                CollapseE(mems.Item(i), mems, i, targetLines)

            Next

        End If


        If (epStart.LessThan(epEnd)) Then
            If IncludeMember(elt) Then
                targetLines.Add(epStart.Line)
            End If
        End If



    End Sub
```